# VHDL for loop limit on clock cycle

Tags: loops, for-loop, vhdl, clock, cycle

I have the following for loop in my code:

```
for index in 0 to a'length-1 loop
  result(index) := a(index) xor bb(index) xor carry_in;
  carry_in := (carry_in and (a(index) or bb(index))) or
              (a(index) and bb(index));
    end loop;
```

It accepts a signal a for 32 bits. So the loop has 32 iterations. I was wondering where the bottleneck is in how many iterations can be run until the FPGA cannot run this code anymore. I am able to synthesize the code, but when I increase the clock frequency higher than 48MHz, the .bit stream file cannot be read anymore by the FPGA. Any frequency lower than 48 MHz is fine.

Is there a kind of bottleneck in the amount of iterations in the for loop on the how long the clock cycle may be?

Comment: How do you increase the clock frequency? Increasing the clock frequency, will cause timing errors (in the report and if certain in the hardware too).

Comment: Did you constraint your clock? You should see timing slack in Static Timing Analysis (STA), and see where the bottleneck is. What fpga/synthesis tool are you using?

Comment: @JonathanDrolet The FPGA has a crystal oscillator of 100 MHz and there is a clock divider that creates a clock signal with a lower frequency. As far as I know, the clock hasn't been contained. I have to investigate the timing report a bit better. I think I did see something about a critical path there. I'm using the xilinx ise tool.

Comment: @Paebbels In the clock divider componenet, there's a multiplier and divider variable and the clock output is based on (multiplier/divider)*systemclock.

Comment: Do you use a PLL to divide the clock? What FPGA are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The count of loop iterations, the size of an FPGA and it's max. clock frequency are not really connected...

The synthesis translates your loop into several stages (your examples has 32).
The more stages you generate, the more FPGA resources are used. So you can fill up a whole FPGA with one loop.

The max. clock frequency depends on the longest path between two flip flops (aka critical path). For example a critical path of 18 ns is equal to a Fmax of circa 50 MHz (see critical path, setup/hold times, static timing analysis for more details on this subject). When your loop produces a long critical path and does not insert pipeline flip flops, then Fmax will decrease. You can also look into your synthesis report for Fmax analysis or other indicators like: Levels of Logic.

If a FPGA does not accept a bit file, then you are uploading the wrong bit file. 
I triggered this by myself. I choose the wrong FPGA size and pinout for a Spartan-3E. This caused the USB/JTAG loader to crash and hangup my USB port and then my PC :(.